# CSS grid dynamic rows and columns

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-grid

I would like to create a table using CSS grid
The table is in the following (poorly drawn but gets the message across) form:
[image]

I'll explain. Let's say that the header cell size is 2x / 2y. Each header row's cell is x / 2y and each header column cell is 2x / y. The internal table cell size (in red) is x / y.

Everything other than the Header cell is dynamic for example I may get 7 rows and 3 columns from the data.

How do I make this table be dynamic?

For the header column I've wrote:

```
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 145px);
```

and for the header rows i've added:

```
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 145px);
```

But I am still missing something. How can I make this table to become dynamic according to the data and according to that size limitations I wrote for each cell?

Comment: your attempted code would be helpful.

Comment: You always set them to 145px width. You can also set a dynamic width like this: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(145px, 1fr))`

Comment: CSS-Grid is not a replacement for tables. i suggest you use teh right tool for the job.

Comment: If you want to make a table dynamic then you have to use tables , not css grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the below is not very practical or useful, thought I'd try it out out of curiosity:

- the `x` and `y` in your question have been kept as CSS variables,
- use `grid-template-columns` similar to what you'd done but with first column width added like `grid-template-columns: calc(var(--x) * 2) repeat(auto-fill, var(--x))`,
- place the first row using `grid-template-rows: calc(var(--y) * 2)`,
- place your rows below the *header* using *implicit grids* - use `grid-auto-rows: var(--y)`.

See demo below:

```css
:root {
  --y: 75px;
  --x: 75px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: calc(var(--x) * 2) repeat(auto-fill, var(--x));
  grid-template-rows: calc(var(--y) * 2);
  grid-auto-rows: var(--y);
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```